# Is the hasOwnProperty method in JavaScript case sensitive?

Tags: javascript

Is `hasOwnProperty()` method case-sensitive? Is there any other alternative case-insensitive version of `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: Java Script is not case insensitive, so there's no alternative on that. But why you want it case insensitive?

Comment: Related: [Are javascript object keys case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42400548/1048572), [Access JavaScript property case-insensitively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12484386/1048572)

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it's case sensitive (so `obj.hasOwnProperty('x') !== obj.hasOwnProperty('X')`) You could extend the Object prototype (some people call that [*monkey patching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)):

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnPropertyCI = function(prop) {
      return ( function(t) {
         var ret = [];
         for (var l in t){
             if (t.hasOwnProperty(l)){
                 ret.push(l.toLowerCase());
             }
         }
         return ret;
     } )(this)
     .indexOf(prop.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
```

More functional:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnPropertyCI = function(prop) {
   return Object.keys(this)
          .filter(function (v) {
             return v.toLowerCase() === prop.toLowerCase();
           }).length > 0;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's case sensitive, because JavaScript is case sensitive.

There is no alternative built-into the language, but you could roll your own:

```
function hasOwnPropertyCaseInsensitive(obj, property) {
    var props = [];
    for (var i in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) props.push(i);
    var prop;
    while (prop = props.pop()) if (prop.toLowerCase() === property.toLowerCase()) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I won't ask *why* you want to do this, I'm sure there's a good reason... also, if you want the actual property in its correct case, replace `return true` with `return prop`

Comment: I commonly use a case in-sensitive check when parsing data from external systems or that might be user entry, because javascript is sensitive, I need to make sure the input is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Old question is old; but still entirely relevant. I searched for a quick answer to this question as well, and ended up figuring out a good solution before I read this, so I thought I'd share it.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object, 'hasOwnPropertyCI', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: (keyName) => (
        Object.keys(this).findIndex(
            v => v.toUpperCase() === keyName.toUpperCase()
        ) > -1
    }
});
```

This resolves to `true` when keyName exists in the object it's called on:

```
var MyObject = { "foo": "bar" };
MyObject.hasOwnPropertyCI("foo");
```

Hope that helps someone else! :D

***PS:*** Personally, my implementation slaps the conditional above into an IF statement, since I won't be using it anywhere else in my application (in addition to the fact that I'm not a huge fan of manipulating native prototypes).

Comment: I like the implementation. The question I have now is how to refer the property if we don't know its case? Say, if (!this.states.hasOwnPropertyCI(area)) {
            this.states[area] = {};
        }

        if (!this.states[area].hasOwnPropertyCI(page)) {
            this.states[area][page] = {};
        }  
How should I use this.states[area] to be able to refer to this property without having area in correct case?

Comment: @Naomi Technically you could modify hasOwnPropertyCI to _return_ the key's actual name if it finds it, rather than just `true`. You can do so simply by using `.find()` instead of `.findIndex()`, and removing the `> -1`