# How to ignore case in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have the following code :-

```
var dataSub = [];

 $.each(dataObj.EmployeeDetail, function (idx, obj) {
            $.each(columnDb, function (idx1, obj1) {
            dataSub.push(obj[obj1.title]);
     });
});
```

In `dataObj.EmployeeDetail` I have data like this :-

```
   Object 0 : { Address1: "123",Address2: null,Category: 1,Children: 0,City: "Xyxz" }
   Object 1 : { Address1: "456",Address2: null,Category: 1,Children: 0,City: "Abc" }
```

In `columnDb`  I have data like this :-

```
Object 0 : title: "ADDRESS1"
Object 1 : title: "CITY"
```

As you can see the data in `columnDB` is in uppercase(dynamic data), my `dataSub` always remains empty because `title` it is not matching with `dataObj.EmployeeDetail`.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think you will have much luck other than updating the keys of `dataObj.EmployeeDetail`

Comment: The selected answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12484507/344140 should get you what you need.  Oops, what ^he said.

Comment: Can you modify `columnDb`?

Comment: Yes I can modify `columnDB`.

Comment: so, either modify the `title` values, or add a new column to `columnDB` containing the mapped field names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var dataSub = [];
    $.each(dataObj.EmployeeDetail, function(idx, obj) {
        var array = $.map(obj, function(value, index) {
            return [value];
        });
        dataSub.push(array);
        $.each(columnDb, function(idx1, obj1) {
            dataSub[idx].push(obj1.title);
        });
    });
    console.log(dataSub);
```

Comment: I got an error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: I made some edits. Try it again