# How to make dictionary search as case insensitive in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have dictionary object `dictionary` withing TypeScript which is storing values in the following fashion:

```
{
  "abc": {
    "country": "Germany",
    "population": 83623528
  },
  "CDE": {
    "country": "Austria",
    "population": 8975552
  },
  "efg": {
    "country": "Switzerland",
    "population": 8616571
  }
}
```

I have another array `tabledata` which is storing values of keys as `Name` but the case for `Name` can be different within array.

Now, I am trying to search for values within dictionary using the following statement:

```
hostDictionary[tableData[i].Name]
```

It works fine when the case matches between `tableData[i].Name` and `dictionary key`

But I am getting null value when the case doesn't match.

For example,

`hostDictionary[tableData[i].Name]` is returning `null` when `tableData[i].Name = "cde"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484386/access-javascript-property-case-insensitively

Comment: Why not use always-lowercase property names in your object?

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over its keys to compare .

> Keys are *case-senstitive*, comparing them after converting lower or
>   upper case will cause inconsistency in your search.

If you want to get the value without minding case.

```
function getKey(key, obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj).find((el) => el.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()) ? obj[el]: null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not be as efficient as a dictionary but this might work.

```
function get(key){ 
   for(let prop in hostDictionary){
     if( prop.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase())
        return hostDictionary[prop];
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use `toUppercase` on each side of the comparison
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

```
const A = 'Asdf'
const B = 'asdf'

A === B // false
A.toUpperCase() === B.toUpperCase() // true
```