# Are javascript object keys case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I was trying to fix duplicate items in an array on javascript by the means of object keys. The loop added 'virtual reality' and 'Virtual Reality' in the same object as different keys. Is there a way to make Javascript object **not** case sensitive ?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have dictionaries, it has objects. Aside from that, strings (which is really what you are talking about) are always case-sensitive.

Comment: yes are case sensitive, but not dictionaries, only objects, but in newer revisions exists Map

Comment: You can always reduce the input to lower case and just compare everything as lower case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484386/access-javascript-property-case-insensitively

Comment: Related: [Access JavaScript property case-insensitively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12484386/1048572), [Is the hasOwnProperty method in JavaScript case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5832888/1048572), [Can an Object have case-insensitive member access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57530678/1048572)

Answer (score 4):

While [object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names) are strings and they are case sensitive, you could use an own standard and use only lower case letters for the access.

You could apply a [`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to the key and use a function as wrapper for the access.

Example with a wrapper object.

```js
function insert(key, value) {
    if (!wrapper[key.toLowerCase()]) {
        wrapper[key.toLowerCase()] = key;
    }
    data[wrapper[key.toLowerCase()]] = value;
}

var data = {},
    wrapper = {};

insert('Foo', 'bar');
console.log(data);
insert('FOO', '42');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I am aware of that method. However, I am using the keys for data visualization and wanted to avoid changing the case.

Comment: in this case, you could use a wraper object with lower case letters for checking.

Answer (score 0):

> Are javascript object keys case sensitive?

Yes, open your favorite browser's console to find your answer.  I used Chrome:

```
var obj = {'one': 1}

obj.one
```

> 1

```
obj.ONE
```

> undefined

```
obj['one']
```

> 1

```
obj['ONE']
```

undefined

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript like most languages is indeed case sensitive.