# Using hasOwnPropertyCI method, but it prints the method when looping through JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Using the method from the [Is the hasOwnProperty method in JavaScript case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832888/is-the-hasownproperty-method-in-javascript-case-sensitive) post, I was able to use it as expected: to check if the json object had the key name while ignoring the case. However, when looping through my JSON object, the method name would print out for a key and the method details would print out as a value.

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnPropertyCI = function(prop) {
    return Object.keys(this)
           .filter(function (v) {
              return v.toLowerCase() === prop.toLowerCase();
            }).length > 0;
 };//checks item exists in json ignoring case


function findOwnPropertyCI(obj, property) {
    var props = [];
    for (var i in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) props.push(i);
    var prop;
    while (prop = props.pop()) if (prop.toLowerCase() === property.toLowerCase()) return prop;
    return false;
}//finds actual casing once confirmed exists


const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.msgs = require ('./hiscores.json');

bot.on('message',message=>{
    let input = message.content;

    if(input.startsWith('$'))
    {
        let command = input.substr(PREFIX.length).split(" ")[0];

        let args = input.substr(input.indexOf(' ')+1);

        switch(command){
            case 'personal':
                playername = args
                if(bot.msgs.hasOwnPropertyCI(playername)){
                    var pers = findOwnPropertyCI(bot.msgs, playername);
                    message.channel.send(pers);
                    for(var bosses in bot.msgs[pers]){
                        message.channel.send(bosses);
                        for(var drops in bot.msgs[pers][bosses]){
                            message.channel.send(drops+": "+bot.msgs[pers][bosses][drops]);
                        }
                    }
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

hiscores.json

```
{
    "Player 1": {
        "Boss 1": {
            "Drop 1": 0,
            "Drop 2": 0,
            "Drop 3": 1,
            "Drop 4": 0
        },
        "Boss 2": {
            "Drop 5": 0,
            "Drop 6": 0,
            "Drop 7": 0,
            "Drop 8": 0,
            "Drop 9": 0,
            "Drop 10": 0
        }
    },
    "Player 2": {
        "Boss 1": {
            "Drop 1": 0,
            "Drop 2": 0,
            "Drop 3": 1,
            "Drop 4": 0
        },
        "Boss 2": {
            "Drop 5": 0,
            "Drop 6": 0,
            "Drop 7": 0,
            "Drop 8": 0,
            "Drop 9": 0,
            "Drop 10": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
$personal Player 1
```

Output:

```
Player 1
Boss 1
Drop 1: 0
Drop 2: 0
Drop 3: 1
Drop 4: 0
hasOwnPropertyCI: function(prop) {
    return Object.keys(this)
           .filter(function (v) {
              return v.toLowerCase() === prop.toLowerCase();
            }).length > 0;
 }
Boss 2
Drop 5: 0
Drop 6: 0
Drop 7: 0
Drop 8: 0
Drop 9: 0
Drop 10: 0
hasOwnPropertyCI: function(prop) {
    return Object.keys(this)
           .filter(function (v) {
              return v.toLowerCase() === prop.toLowerCase();
            }).length > 0;
 }
hasOwnPropertyCI
hasOwnPropertyCI: function(prop) {
    return Object.keys(this)
           .filter(function (v) {
              return v.toLowerCase() === prop.toLowerCase();
            }).length > 0;
 }
```

Comment: Don't use both `hasOwnPropertyCI` and then `findOwnPropertyCI`. Just try to find it, then when that returns `undefined` you know it doesn't have any.

Comment: Btw you really should just store the lowercased names in the highscores object, then you can just access it directly and don't have to search for it.